# Cannot convert from char to char*

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

Can some tell me please why I get this? It doesn't make sense.

```
 enum type{
     Entity = 1,
     String = 2,
     Vector = 4,
     Float = 5,
     Integer = 6
 };

template <typename t>
t field(){
     t out;
     float* fOut;

     //Get the return type
     switch(getType(0)){ //This isn't needed, just ignore it :)
         case Integer:
            out = getInt(5);//int getInt(int test) { return test; }
         break;
         case Float:
            out = getFloat(1.7f);//int getFloat(float test) { return test; }
         break;
         case String:
            out = getString(":(");//int getString(char* test) { return test; }
         break;
         case Vector:
            getVector(0);//int getString(float* test) { return test; }
         break;
     }

     return out;
}
```

For some odd reason, I get these errors. I thought a template variable can hold any data type :L
[image]

Comment: `I thought a template variable can hold any data type`  You have a misunderstanding of what a template is.

Comment: What do all your `getXxx()` functions return? They need to return a value of type `t`.

Comment: So should I do out = (t)getXxx() ?

Comment: @VMNova `So should I do out = (t)getXxx() `.  What are you really trying to accomplish with this code?  A template is supposed to be typesafe so that no casting needs to be done.  As a matter of fact, the whole thing with the `switch` defeats the purpose of the template.

Comment: Here's a better example of what I'm trying to do. https://i.imgur.com/ykh6643.png

Comment: @VMNova Don't describe with showing us more code.  What is the purpose of the code you are writing?  It certainly is not template worthy as it stands.  Good template code shouldn't need to test what types are coming in like that.  Might as well just create an overloaded function and forego templates.

Comment: There's a crucial difference between your code and the code you are trying to emulate. Your code `t out;`, other code `object returnValue = null;`. In your code the return type is the template parameter `t`, in the other code the return type is a generic base type which is later converted to the templated type.

Comment: @VMNova **C# is not C++**.

Comment: You might want to try Boost.Variant: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html

Comment: Sorry &PaulMcKenzie, this was at night and I was quite tired. This should sum up what I'm trying to do.

http://prntscr.com/82ffos

Answer (score 1):

You may only assign types that are convertable to type `t` to `out`.

You have called `field<char*>()` so you may only assign types convert to a `char*`. The `char*` that you called `field` with determines the type of `out`.

C++ is [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing). Don't let the `template` confuse you. That's turned into a regular looking function by the compiler at compile time. So the code the compiler is actually giving the warning on looks like this:

```
char* field(){
     char* out;
     float* fOut;

     //Get the return type
     switch(getType(0)){ //This isn't needed, just ignore it :)
     case Integer:
        out = getInt(5);//int getInt(int test) { return test; }
     break;
     case Float:
        out = getFloat(1.7f);//int getFloat(float test) { return test; }
     break;
     case String:
        out = getString(":(");//int getString(char* test) { return test; }
     break;
     case Vector:
        getVector(0);//int getString(float* test) { return test; }
     break;
     }

     return out;
}
```

Comment: But I want to return an int, float, and float* type.

Comment: `But I want to return an int, float, and float* type.`  You see that you can't do that if `out` is  a `char *`.  Your `out` is of type `t` and in the instantiation of `field<char *>`, `t` becomes `char *`.

Comment: @VMNova If you read the link you see that strongly typed languages, like C/C++, can ONLY assign to `out` types which convert to `char*`. We cannot help you with a solution until you provide more information on what you're trying to do. *Why* do you want to assign to a `char*`? What are you going to do with it. If you just want to obtain a `string` representation of the value, `stringstream` may be a good option.